# What is the equivalent of a heap dump in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, performance, database-performance

Doing some reading about Oracle database and I'm learning about Shared Pools.

I used this as my main reference: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_shared_pool.htm#TGDBA558

After reading this one thing I’m still not clear on is how we can get a “dump” of the shared pool

For example, let's say I have an application that is having memory consumption issues / errors due to an over stressed shared pool... how would I go about finding out what stored procs, string variable contents, etc is eating up all the storage?

In Java we would simply take a Heap dump. The heap dump shows packages, classes, raw data that was in the memory.

What is the equivalent of a heap dump in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Oradebug](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oradebug)

From the page:

> Oradebug is a command that can be executed from SQL*Plus (or Svrmgrl
>   in Oracle 8i and lower releases) to display or dump diagnostics
>   information.

Brief explanation on dumps [here](https://orainternals.wordpress.com/2009/01/15/a-stroll-through-shared-pool-heaps/) and [here](http://www.orafaq.com/papers/oradebug.pdf).

Comment: Cool! Thanks. So are there any built in tools from oracle that do this same thing? Or maybe without bells and whistles?

Comment: According to the second link, "This tool is primarily used by Oracle
worldwide customer support". I am actually not sure if there is anything else you could use.

Answer (score 3):

When you dump Oracle's shared pool you will get a file having tens of gigabytes. And you will block the whole database till it is done. 
This is something you usually do NOT want to do on production database.

Oracle's diagnostic capabilities are far beyond of JVM can provide.

- For a brief view on memory usage you van use `V$SGASTAT` and `v$sga_resize_ops`
- First of all you can also look into the past and can analyze past problems. google for AWR, ASH, STATSPACK reports.
- Blocking problems you can use hang analyze tool
- For data consistency problems you can use auditing or logminer
- For detailed tracing a single session you can use tkprof, trca or even real-time sql monitoring. or `v$active_session_history`.

Oracle has something called *wait interface* so whenever the database spends some time doing something, some counter is increased. There are various tools which access these counters. Each of them serves for a particular purpose.

So yes, you can also dump Oracle's shared pool, but this is usually last resort way, how to diagnose problems in Oracle.

Comment: Great answer. I would like to challenge you a bit on it - 

You said it's more powerful than a Java heapdump. OK I would like to challenge you to answer a question then - how do I dump the varchar contents of a particular parse in the shared pool?

Meaning i have a parse that is doing this: `2 + 50 * .50325`
But what i want is this: `:initial + :fees * :factor` so it can be reusable.

So i'll make a fix to get those in.

I would like to search the shared storage for a keyword ":initial + :fees" to make sure my substitution is working.  

java heap dumps make this easy. thoughts?

Comment: `select * from v$sql where sql_text like = 'any text you want'`. Oracle concept is different. Imagine that JVM could providee information for every method; how many times it was called, execution time, and if if was blocked, then by whom.